# Is there any way to apply spirit animation for element and its pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, pseudo-element

### I'm trying to solve this challenge on my way to learn web dev

1. Here is basically What I want do to,

---

[The Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P61I.gif)

2. This my css code

---

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50% auto;
    border: solid 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: dodgerblue dodgerblue dodgerblue transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }

div:hover::before, div:hover::after {
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

div:hover {
    animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    width: 130%;
    height: 130%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: goldenrod transparent goldenrod goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

div::after {
    content: "";
    width: 160%;
    height: 160%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: transparent black black black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

3. The goal is acheive this animation when **hovering** and make it only **1s duration time** for the *blue* element with only ***one html div element***

---

4. Becuase it's one html div element, I can't spirit the pseudo class rule from its parent element, the div:hover css role keep override the pseudo class role. There must be a way that idk about to achieve it

---

*I've tried different ways but nothing seems to work.*

**thanks.**